# How to locally test Django project accessing it using example.com domain?

Tags: django, testing, localhost, ip-address, tld

I'm willing to test Django project, but I want to access it using “example.com“. Before I used “127.0.0.1:8000“ (`manage.py runserver`), but now I have need to test how my project acts on different TLDs. All I want to do is somehow tell my computer that “example.com“ points to “127.0.0.1:8000“. I don't want others to have access to it, so it's not question about deployment.

I am Linux user. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo vi /etc/hosts` and add the following line at the end.

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

Also, if you run the web server as root, you can use port 80 and not have to type `example.com:8000` into the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

change the hosts file at `/etc/hosts`

Comment: add a line like this:

127.0.0.1 example.com

than whenever some app in your computer will try to connect to `example.com` it will connect to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Just edit `/etc/hosts` so that `example.com` maps to that 127.0.0.1.

I don't think you can map it to a specific port number though, so you'll need to either access `example.com:8000` or run the server on port 80 (probably via sudo).

Answer (score 0):

Simple, edit your hosts file at /etc/hosts so that your site "example.com" maps to the localhost "127.0.0.1"